# Will an egg-laying animal lay eggs in a forbidden nest?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have set up a small pen in my fortress, equipped with a nest box with a few captured Cave crocodiles inside. The Cave crocodiles are all **trained**, and they are **not restrained** in any way.

[image: Capture of the pen showing that the nest box is claimed by a Cave Crocodile.]

To prevent the dwarfs from collecting the eggs, I have forbidden the nest box with `d-b-f`. The nest box was already claimed by a Cave crocodile previously.

So far the Cave crocodile hasn't laid a single egg after forbidding the building. **Does building forbiddance also affect the way animals interact with them**? If so, what can I do to prevent my dwarves from collecting the eggs and allowing the crocodiles to breed?